# Social Media Icons disappeared on my Online Website while they appeared on my offline website

Tags: css, font-awesome, offline-browsing

Social Media Icons disappeared on my Online Website while they appeared on my offline website:

[Icons appear in yellow circles in my Offline Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU3l7.png)

[Icons disappear in yellow circles in my Online Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbSRk.png)

Comment: Show you code so far so that we can help

Comment: Probably cannot find the path to the source or cannot load external fonts due to security reasons. Use your browsers dev tools to inspect the loaded fonts and icons.

Comment: How are you loading your icon's to your website ?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to help you without any additional information.

The only reason that I can come up with for your items to disappear in the online version is a missing or corrupted path.

That could be explained by e.g. missing the icons folder when uploading the web content.

I will provide a more detailed answer once you provide us with the necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply. I have just solved the issue by updating the font-awesome.min.css version from: 4.3.0 to: 4.7.0. And it works well.

this one:

link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

instead of:

link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css